# How to lock(exclusive) a record during a function call in pgsql?

Tags: postgresql

In `pgsql`, how may I lock a record during a function run? considering the following function.

```
create or replace function foo.bar_func(int)returns int as $$

with s as (select * from foo.bar where id=$1);--  <--lock the fetched row [BEGIN]
/*
Some query, update, insert, ...
*/
select coalesce(s.id,-1) from s;--return something.
-- <-- release the locked row [END]
$$ language sql;
```

I like to lock the row(if found) at the begin of function, till it finishes its work.
How does `pg_advisory_lock(bigint)` work? does it help here?
what is the difference with `select for update`?

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT … FOR UPDATE` does what you expect, namely locks the returned rows exclusively until the end of the current transaction ([see here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE)).

Advisory locks, on the other hand, are application defined. They are held either until the end of the current transaction or until the end of the current session ([see here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS)). Thus, they need to be checked manually and you may need to release them manually.

If you want to use variables (like `s` in your sample code), you have to use PL/pgSQL. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to make your function transactional. Instead, it will be always executed in the context of the surrounding transaction. Adding an `EXCEPTION` clause to your function causes the function to be wrapped in a subtransaction ([see here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)), but locks acquired by your function will be held until the end of the surrounding transaction. I tested with PG 9.3.